# Does Jsonata support nested ternary operator?

Tags: jsonata

How to write nested if else using JSONata?

I was expecting this to work:

```
$append(array_1, $map(array_2, function($v, $i, $a){
     ($v in array_2 and $v in array_1)? none : 
     (($v in array_2 and $v not in array_1)? none: $v) }))
```

Unfortunately, it didn't.
array_1 and array_2 are

```
{
    "array_1": [
        "www.microsoft.com",
        "4.4.4.4",
        "www.gitlab.com"
    ],
    "array_2": [
        "4.4.4.4",
        "www.dead.net",
        "www.archive.org"
    ]
}
```

Basically, I'm looking to do a difference of Array_1 and Array_2, ie, all elements in array_1 but not in array_2, so that my final output is `["www.microsoft.com","www.gitlab.com"]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to use nested ternaries for this problem, but you can definitely rely on them:

```
$filter(array_1, function($v) {
  $v in array_2 and $v in array_1
    ? false 
    : $v in array_2 and $not($v in array_1)
      ? false 
      : true
})
```

Live playground: https://stedi.link/8qRJ0Ym

A more straightforward solution for it in my opinion would be:

```
$filter(array_1, function($v) {
  $v in array_1 and $not($v in array_2)
})
```

or even:

```
array_1[$ in $$.array_1 and $not($ in $$.array_2)]
```

Playground: https://stedi.link/OKJnpAs